# using new with a variable that is assigned a function does not have an assigned __proto__

Tags: javascript

I just started reading about Javascript and I cant seem to find the asnwer to this question.Suppose I have a function called `test` and an anonymous function assigned to a variable say `temp`. I noticed that when I create a new object instance with new using a variable as in example 2 no `__proto__` is assigned ? Why is that

```js
function test() {
  this.name = "testerName";
}

var temp = function() {
  this.name = "testeragain";
}

// Example 1:
var d = new test();
console.log(d.__proto__) //prints test{}
console.log(d.__proto__ == test.prototype) //Returns false ? shouldnt this
// Example 2:
var d = new temp();
console.log(d.__proto__) //prints {} ?Why is this?
```

I am running my file using command `node test.js`

Comment: Because your debugger chose not to name it. Notice that both `d` inherit from their respective prototypes - you would get the same result for `console.log(test.prototype); console.log(temp.prototype);`

Comment: You should use `Object.getPrototypeOf(d)`. The `__proto__` getter is deprecated.

Comment: @Bergi I tried using using `Object.getPrototypeOf(d)` and i am gettign the same result. could that be because i am using node to run the js file ?

Comment: Use d.constructor if you want to fetch the constructor fn

Comment: @JamesFranco: I didn't say it changes anything about the result :-) It's just that `temp` has no `.name` (yet), so `console.log` can't show one.

Comment: I extended my answer, hopefully that will make it clearer.

Comment: @Bergi I updated my question . incase console.log has a different behaviour shouldnt it return true for `console.log(d.__proto__ == test.prototype)` ?

Comment: @Bergi—according to [*ECMAScript 2016*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) it's [*required when the ECMAScript host is a web browser … but optional if the ECMAScript host is not a web browser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers). It's not in previous versions though (gotta love these annual updates of the spec…).

Comment: `d.__proto__ == test.prototype` returns false because in example 2 *d* is an instance of *temp*, not *test*.

Comment: @RobG but the proto of both are similar isnt that correct ?

Comment: "Similar" in that they are both objects, but they are different objects. Two objects are never `==` or `===` to each other, i.e. `test.prototype != temp.prototype`.

Comment: @RobG: that it's standardised for compatibility doesn't make it less deprecated and bad style. You should have stopped using it a long time ago.

Comment: @Rob I am sorry  i had an error in my code which i fixed. Isnt `console.log(d.__proto__ == test.prototype)` be true ?

Comment: @Bergi—never used `__proto__` and never will, I don't agree with putting it in ECMA-262, but I have zero influence on the standard authors. :-(

Comment: @JamesFranco—you moved the line of code up to before the re–assignment and now it returns true, happy daze. :-)

Comment: @RobG yes its working now. I just wanted to make sure i know what was in the proto. Seems like accessing the __proto__ property is not really encouraged.

Comment: @JamesFranco—the `__proto__` property was not well regarded, [*Object.getPrototypeOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.getprototypeof) is the standardised equivalent. But if you need to get an Object's `[[Prototype]]` then likely there's a better way to do what your trying to do—unless it's just for an exercise in learning how the language works of course. ;-)

Comment: @RobG thanks for the pointer. I am currently just trying to grasp some understanding of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> no `__proto__` is assigned ?

Of course it is. In both cases `d.__proto__` returns the prototype. The difference is only how `console.log` *chooses to render that value*. If you use `console.dir` instead you should see that those objects are (almost) the same.

Here is an example that demonstrates how the `console.log` output can differ:

```
> console.log({constructor: function foo() {}});
foo { constructor: [Function: foo] }

> console.log({constructor: function bar() {}});
bar { constructor: [Function: bar] }

> console.log({constructor: function () {}});
{ constructor: [Function] }
```

Do you see that the objects are basically the same, except that the functions assigned to `constructor` have different (or no) names?

`console.log` simply prefixes the representation of the object with the value of `constructor.name`.

> prints {} ?Why is this?

The console tries to infer the "type" of the object *somehow*. Since the first function has a *name* (test) it will use that name as the "type" in the output.

The second function doesn't have a name so it doesn't know what to show.

More concretely

```
console.log(d.constructor.name)
```

will log `"test"` for the first function and an empty string (`""`) for the second function.

The behavior of `console.log` is not standardized and the output can differ between <del>browsers</del> JavaScript environments. Functionally wise both examples are identical.

Comment: Yes i am using node to run the js example

Comment: thanks for clearing that up in that case wouldnt `console.log(d.__proto__ == test.prototype)`